# I just want to know if my pinarello is legit and what is the model. The serial number at the bottom is 00000_05430

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike, hybrid-bike

Pinarello serial number is 00000-05430 bought it second hand from my boss.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no public database of serial numbers. If you want to ask if a serial number is legit, ask the Pinarello company. Here you can only ask whether a bike looks like a real Pinarello, but for that you need to show more pictures of the bike, not of the serial number. After the edit is approved we will be able to see two pictures of the bike, but more may be needed depending on what people who know these bikes will say.

Comment: For an aluminium model such as this, does it matter so much if it's genuine or not?

Comment: Is this your bike ?   https://www.carousell.ph/p/pinarello-dogmak-road-bike-1022561252/

Comment: I bet they all have the same frame serial number too.

Answer (score 12):

It's a fake.

- The Dogma K was only made in carbon this bike is certainly not
  carbon.
- This bike also misses the asymmetric rear end with curved seat stays.
- Finally this bike doesn't have the very recognisable ONDA fork.

An authentic Dogma K should look like the one below:
[image]
https://www.roadbikereview.com/threads/dogma-k-anyone.327176/

Comment: I notice the fake fork has a paint scheme that tries to duplicate the wibbly-wobbly look of the fork.   Also, internal vs external cabling, and the "armpit"  between the toptube/headtube/downtube is noticeably different.

Comment: @ChrisH Is this the bent fork you were referring to?

Answer (score 10):

The Pinarello Dogma K is a drop-bar road racing bike from the early 2010's  It was ridden in top-tier races like Paris-Roubaix.

For someone to convert it to a flat bar would be an odd choice given its cost, though not impossible.

---

Google image search returns a lot of white "pinarello" frames in your country that all have a similar paint scheme.  Example

[image]

I see a listing at https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/road-bike-700c-frame-set-and-fork-alloy-crvelo-size-48-top-tube-50-seat-tube-48-i451602276.html  if you inspect the last two photos, they're a dead-ringer for your frame.

When the listing can't spell out the full name like `Cervelo` and has to resort to `C*rvelo`  you know something's not authentic.

[image]

Then take the listing price of **₱5,499.00** and that is $100-$110 USD.

- Your bike has external cable routing, the authentic one has internal.
- The area aft of the headtube is a point on your frame, the authentic has a noticeable curve.
- Your bike has welds, meaning its probably aluminium.  The authentic bike is Carbon Fibre and that does not have welds.
- Your fork has straight legs/tines whereas the original has strange wibbly-wobbly ones.  Yours tries to visually look similar with the paint job.
- The K in your dogma logo has red on the lower half, whereas on the real bike the red is on the top half of the K.

An authentic Dogma K may be found at https://www.bikeradar.com/features/pro-bike/pro-bike-edvald-boasson-hagens-pinarello-dogma-k/ and is worth over $12k USD.  Your frame is priced at $110 USD new.

Sorry - its a fake.  Might be a perfectly adequate frame for riding, but its not what its labelled as.     Since you've already bought it you're stuck with it.

1. Give it a good wash and clean.  Remove wheels.
2. Check closely all the welds, wear areas.  Look for rubbing or cracks.  If none found the frame should be okay to ride for years.
3. Reassemble and give it a front-to-back M check.  Tweak anything that needs it.
4. Ride it!   Any bike beats walking.

You could happily repaint this bike and make it your own.  Perhaps even make new decals that say "fauxnarello" or "Bree's Bike" and customise it how you want.

Comment: I'm gutted for the OP but I love the fauxnarello idea.

Comment: Good list of "fake frame" signs. Another possible one: looking at the second photo from the OP, it appears to be a square taper BB. I couldn't immediately find the specs for this model, but 2010-ish Pinarellos appear to mostly use newer Hollowtech type BBs.

Comment: @pateksan I want it to be "Pinoyrello"