# Is this Pinarello fake?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I just want to make sure that the bike is not fake before buying it. I saw it in fb marketplace. could anyone help me whether it's fake or not? I asked the company and didn't get any answer

[image: Bottom view of bottom bracket showing serial number]
[image: Overall side view of bike]
[image: Close-up of crank]
[image: Close-up of designer signature at bottom of down tube]
[image: Close-up of rear derailleur]

Comment: What makes you suspect it might be a fake? Price? lack of papers? Seller conduct?

Comment: There are loads of fake ones out there. If it has an Italian thread bottom bracket, that is a good indicator it's genuine.

Comment: It looks more legit than the last pinarellfaux at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/85258/i-just-want-to-know-if-my-pinarello-is-legit

Comment: Your other enormous risk is whether the bike is stolen.

Comment: If the price is hard to believe, stolen is about 10,000x more likely than counterfeit.

Comment: If this is a fake, I would say someone has gone to a lot of effort because off the images it seems pretty convincing.  About the only thing looks a little off to me vs pics of current models is where the seat stays joining the seat post relative to the top tube, that could be a model/year/size thing though.  Sure you've already found this https://pinarello.com/global/en/false-frames

Comment: Would also add and admit could also be counterfeit.  The fact it's equipped with Ultegra group set makes me think it's pretty heigh end.  Would expect fakes to have pretty generic or entry level components.  Even if it is a fake frame, might be worth it for the components alone

Comment: Looks suspicious to me. No one who legitimately owns a Pinarello like that would stage it with the front wheel in the stand like that!! ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Das ist eine sehr gute kopie ist nicht original Pinarello

This is a very good copy is not original Pinarello

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Please note that you should post your answer in English.  That said, you assert it's a fake but don't give any understanding as to why.  What are the giveaways that it's a fake?  As it is a short answer like this, even if it's correct, doesn't really help.

Comment: Please give more detail.  Use [edit] to add info to your answer.