# I would like to know if a Pinarello is authentic or not - how to tell?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike, pinarello

[image]

I bought a used Pinarello and would like to know if it is authentic or not.

Comment: Is it too late to ask the seller for the original documentation and sales receipt, etc.?

Comment: @Criggie Easy to fake some A4 laser prints.

Comment: Have a browse through https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=pinarello  there are a lot of questions like this some with excellent answers and links.

Comment: @Criggie I read the topics, it didn’t help much (maybe I didn’t understand something).
I sent the serial number to pinarello, but they answer something for a long time.

Comment: I can upload more photos if that helps.

Comment: @Sergey More photos will help.  But from what I can see, *if* that's a fake, it's a very good one.  The parts of the finish that are visible appear very well-done - there's no roughness to the matt/gloss black borders, for example.  And the wavy fork and seat stays seem dead-on - on the fakes I've seen posted online those are usually botched at least some, if there's even an attempt to fake them.

Comment: @AndrewHenle https://imgur.com/a/CEGUYD7

Comment: If you want to see a knockoff dogma, check out  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/85265/19705

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See **UPDATE** below...

A 2012 Pinarello Dogma seems like a perfect match for your frame.  Later Pinarellos have the seat stays meeting the seat tube below the level of where the top tube meets the seat tube.

[**Check out Mark Cavendish's 2012 Pinarello Dogma 2**](https://road.cc/content/feature/check-out-mark-cavendishs-2012-pinarello-dogma-2-301383)

[image]

It does look like you have a larger frame than the one Cavendish rode.

[This 59.5 cm 2012 Dogma 2 seems like a much closer match](https://www.theproscloset.com/products/2347897749586-pinarello-dogma-2-59-5cm-bike-2012)

[image]

**UPDATE**

Given the photo the OP posted in the comments:

[image]

The bike would be a Pinarello Paris.  Which does match the OPs bike better - the only year Dogmas had external shift cables was 2009.  After that, the Dogma had internally-routed shifter cables.

That image appears smudged and not something likely to come from a mainstream production Pinarello.  However, the clear-coat finish over the carbon fiber is spotless - I seriously doubt any forgery would be that good, and a repair job would have to be exceptional.

The complexities of the frame and the paint job seem far beyond what a forger could do, and the paint job with its shifting between gloss and matte finishes and AFAICT a defectless clear coat seems like a stretch for any repair job.

And then throw in the 70mm Italian BB, which is something no forger would likely get correct.

I'd say it's almost certain you have a low-production/special order/prototype Pinarello Paris.  They do exist - I raced on November Bicycle's prototype white Wheelhouse frame...

Although it could be a repainted/repaired one - but from the pictures you posted that would be one *exceptional* repainting.

Answer (score 2):

Real Pinarello has Italian thread bottom bracket. If BSC, fake.

Some older carbon models had pressfit.

That's a start for you.

Comment: can I find out the type of attachment without disassembling anything?

Comment: I saw the data written on the carriage. SMBB 6700 36x24 According to information from the Internet, it says: "Standard Hollowtech II, compatible with all systems of this standard and analogues. size 68 mm: thread 1.37 x 24 tpi ; size 70 mm: 1.36 x 24 tpi" I understand correctly that I have a 70mm size, so this is an Italian thread? BSC have 68 mm, I found out

Answer (score 2):

I have the same frame but from 2014 with internal cable routing. The livery looks on point but a couple of differences stand out to me:

- can't see in the photo but it seems like you are missing the logo letter "P" on the front of the headset
- headset cap should say Pinarello (?)
- seat post should be by "MOST"

That's all I can see based on that one blurry photo you posted.

[image: this is my ride]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the photo album in the comments on the OP, it claims to be a Pinarello Paris.
Pinarello have some guidance and are willing to help identify frames.  See their FAQ here: https://pinarello.com/global/en/faqs

At first glance, it does look like a 2011 Paris, even the UCI approval sticker has the correct number: https://archive.uci.org/docs/default-source/equipment/liste-des-modeles-de-cadres-et-fourches-homologues---list-of-approved-models-of-frames-and-forks.pdf

However, there are a number of areas of paintwork that make me think it is either fake or has been repaired/repainted.
The paint scheme doesnt match any images of a Paris i can find:

- Asymmetrical wording seems wrongly placed
- Onda lettering on fork does not seem correct
- No lettering on chainstay
- Very low quality Paris 50HM sticker on top tube.

You can find how a 2011 Paris should look here:

Comment: Shimano chain, bought a new one, little wear.

Comment: "Onda lettering on fork does not seem correct" ; i have like in this image:
https://imgur.com/a/WgvRj1l ... https://www.competitivecyclist.com/pinarello-fp-quattro-ultegra-di2-bike ... https://imgur.com/lOC4Qv8