# Pinarello FP3 30HM12K real or not?

Tags: road-bike, frames, identify-this-bike, pinarello, fake

https://link.marktplaats.nl/m2032857289

Is this Pinarello FP3 real or fake?

Serial number: 30HM12K

Who explain to me. See the comments under please.

Comment: Ask the seller for proof/evidence?

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/90026/i-would-like-to-know-if-a-pinarello-is-authentic-or-not-how-to-tell

Comment: Just a gut feeling, but if the signature fork/seatstay shapes are present, it's very likely an original. Pinarello and certified dealers also have a counterfeit check, afaik based on the serial number, dunno how far back in model year but worth a try.

Comment: Probably genuine. Check the catalogue for that year. The Most brand components are unique to Pinarello and should help identification.

Answer (score 1):

Thank to you all! I have to do my researche. Have a picture of the serial number en will check this on the Pinarello registers. When i look to more similar bikes, i think it’s a fake one:

https://www.81496.com/jouhou/road/pinarello2010/fp3.html

Chinese chinarello?!

Greetz Willem

[image]

Comment: Have you taken into account the points mentioned in the comments under the question, like frame details?

Comment: Yes sure, who closed my forum? Why?